# Converting multiple columns to double type in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with a lot of columns containing decimal values in string format and  I am trying to find a way to convert all the columns containing numerical values into double type. For example by specifying the range of columns to convert, df[2:4] in this case.

From this:

```
df <- data_frame(cat = c('A', 'B', 'C'), 
             X11 = c('0.1', '0.3', '0.5'), 
             Y2 = c('0.2', '0.2', '0.7'), 
             P3 = c('0.14', '0.31', '0.35'),
             type = c('H', 'I', 'J'))
```

To this:

```
df <- data_frame(cat = c('A', 'B', 'C'), 
             X11 = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5), 
             Y2 = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.7), 
             P3 = c(0.14, 0.31, 0.35),
             type = c('H', 'I', 'J'))
```

I have been trying to get it to work with the different dplyr mutate functions but I cannot figure out how to do it.

I would be super grateful if I could get some advice on this one.

Comment: How did those values end up being character values in the first place? Normally when you import your data the conversion should happen automatically. Do you know what caused the problem in the first place? It's usually better to try to fix the root cause than clean up with mess later on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would be better to do this with `type.convert` from `base R` which automatically correct the type based on the value in each column

```
df1 <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```

---

In `dplyr`, it can be done with `across` and specify the range of columns with either numeric index

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(2:4, as.numeric))
```

Or the column names range

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(X11:P3, as.numeric))
```